# Name of anime where the winner of a competition would inherit the forest

Tags: baby-baachan

I saw it in 2004/5 so must have been released way earlier.
It wasn't in the normal shoujo/shonen style drawing either.

All I remember is that there was a competition and the winner would inherit the forest. And people from evil compainies were buying/bribing the winners to win and give them the forest for industrial purposes.

Our protagonist is a girl and she is not interested but takes part anyway.
There were some rather quirky moments which I remember such as:

- During the competition there was a task where they had to take water out of a big bottle. A lot of them used a straw for this one.
- The last round was between the protagonist and an intelligent girl with glasses and a laptop. The protagonist wins after deciding not to answer the question as answering the question correctly would have caused the glasses-girl to fall into the water.

Yep! That's it. Please help me! I really am not able to find this!

Answer (score 4):

I know this anime. It's [**Baby Baachan**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2732/Baby_Baachan).

[image: Baby Baachan]

The main girl is Amika, who fights to save the forest which her grandmother has protected. The other girls are other granddaughters of the grandmother. The grandmother possesses her baby brother's body and tries to teach Amika how to win. She hates it till the end. The rounds go exactly as you say. In between, the grandmother/baby offers useful tips like cutting onions without crying, etc.

I will never forget this anime because the tips in this series helped me a lot in life when I was young. Hope this helped :D